# Windows 7 comes to a near-halt every week and then flushes memory

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, cpu, freeze

I have a very strange issue that's been puzzling me for a long time. I have a Windows 7 system with 16GB RAM. Every week or so, usually at some point during the first few days of the week, and at a point when the amount of RAM used by the system has built up a lot, the system will slow down drastically to the point where it's almost frozen (the mouse cursor will move only in a very jerky fashion, and most active programs will stop responding) and the CPU's will peg to 100% usage. This state of affairs will go on for about 5 to 10 minutes, and then the computer will return to normal operation, with the memory "flushed" - that's the best word I can think of to describe it; the system will be using a LOT less RAM than before this process or whatever it is started. e.g., before the system more or less locked up it would be using 8.8GB RAM, and after it unfreezes and returns to normal it will be using 5.8GB RAM. I have checked and I'm pretty sure it's neither disk defrag (which is set to run at 1 am every Wednesday, this happens at random times once a week) nor antivirus scan. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you ever reboot?

Comment: well, if the CPU goes to 100% usage where ar you seeing that and why don't you check what process(s) is using that 100%? also I don't know if this has or could even possibly have anything to do with it but it may be worth turning off indexing.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your computer stats in task manager? Be aware that RAM is not the only factor when seeing symptoms like low frame rates for cursors and lag in general. Your RAM isn't anywhere near max capacity when you describe your symptoms. Based on the limited specs you gave us I would guess **slow hard drive**.

Comment: You definitely want to figure out what it's doing when the CPU is pegged.

Comment: try to post a picture of RAMMap when you run into this issue.

Comment: It sounds as though you have a program (possibly a service) with a memory leak.  It fills up your RAM then crashes.  At that point, Windows cleans up the memory.  The program then restarts (which implies a service) and the process repeats.  As others have said - look at Process Explorer but also look at the Event Log to see if anything has stopped and restarted.

Comment: Interesting comments that mirror my answer even though that has been downvoted by some anonymous "benefactor".

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a tool such as process explorer or resource monitor to see what is using up all the RAM. It sounds like you have an application with a memory leak running in the background.

It has nothing to do with disk fragmentation. You need to find out what application(s) are using up the RAM. I see this most commonly with Java applications.

The high CPU might be due to sudden swap activity (the system trying to free ram by writing lower priority memory to the swap file). Anti-Virus tools can also spike like that if sudden disk activity kicks in.

Telling us what is running would also be helpful.